# Check Buttons not firing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this example as a guide to build a checkbox button set; however, it is not firing for me.
Within a class I have a function that consists of the button:

```
check = CheckButtons(rax,('Button 1', 'Button 2', 'Button 3'), (True,False,False))
```

then I have this function within a class... where it looks like:

```
def clickButtons(self,label):
```

and in another method in the same class I am attempting to call it with the following...

```
self.check.on_clicked(self.clickButtons())
```

From this website:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/check_buttons.html

matplotlib button page states:

> on_clicked(func) When the button is clicked, call func with button
>   label
>
> A connection id is returned which can be used to disconnect

However, my current error says that:

> TypeError: clickButtons() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Can someone please explain to me what is going on... how I'm I suppose to know which Button is being pressed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste in a (minimal) bit of the context for this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `check.on_clicked` is used to register a call back for when the check box is clicked.  You need to pass it, as an argument, a function object which takes one argument `label`.  The syntax you want to use is:

```
check.on_clicked(my_obj.clickButtons)
```

There are two important things to understand here.  First, in Python *everything* is an object.  Functions are just objects that happen to have an attribute `__call__`.  The second, is that when you bind a member function to an instance of a class, the instance object is the implicit first argument, thus `my_obj.clickButtons` is an object which as a function which takes one argument.

When you call `check.on_clicked(self.clickButtons())` you are saying 'call the function `on_clicked` on the object `check` using the results of the call `self.clickButtons()` as the argument'.  The call to `clickButtons` throws the error you see because it requires 2 arguments (the implicit `self` and `label`) and you are calling it with only one argument (the implicit `self`).

If you have a class `A`, with function `f(self,b)`, and in instance `a` of `A`, the following two are equivalent

```
a.f(1)      # call member function f on a
A.f(a,1)    # call member function f on a
```

Comment: thank you for your input, but when I do this, it gives me the error saying...

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @freedom see edit.  You would use self if you are calling the function from with in an instance method of your class.  If you have an instance of your class (called `my_obj`) then you would use what I changed it to.